# Decode properties of ByteArrayOutputStream

Tags: java, docker, containers

I'm sending asking the container to `echo STDOUT`

```
ByteArrayOutputStream  out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

InputStream stdin = new ByteArrayInputStream("echo STDIN\n".getBytes()); 

dockerClient.execStartCmd(container.getId())
            .withExecId(execCreateCmdResponse.getId())
            .withStdIn(stdin)
            .withTty(true)
            .withDetach(false)
            .exec(new ExecStartResultCallback(out, err))
            .awaitCompletion(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

but instead I'm receiving `[?1034hsh-4.2#` . This seems like an encoding issue. How do I fix this?

Comment: Which base image do you use for your docker container?

Comment: Because what you are seeing is a shell prompt and some escape sequences, probably these: [Bash Prompt Escape Sequences](http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prompt-HOWTO/bash-prompt-escape-sequences.html)

Comment: Also edit your question and make clear where `dockerClient` comes from. So include the `import ...` line